# How to Add 802.11ac USB wifi adapter in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I ran the

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
```

command and got (not sure it is showing usb wifi dongle)

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10bd] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:0001]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 02)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:5392]
    Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT5392 PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1814:f053]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
04:00.0 IDE interface [0101]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE6101/6102 single-port PATA133 interface [11ab:6101] (rev b2)
```

also driver on CD with dongle has name (bit of gibberish to me) I am afraid

rtl8821CU_WiFi_linux_v5.2.5.1_22211.20170517_COEX20170310-1212.rar

ran lsusb and got (think dongle is not recognised)

Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:5c17 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet P2055 series
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 1908:2310 GEMBIRD 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 04f2:0111 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-9908 Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 1267:0201 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc A4Tech SWOP-3 Mouse
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

Comment: Please identify your exact Wi/Fi device by running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` in terminal. Then [edit] and copy/paste to your question. It probably needs drivers and drivers are hardware specific.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.